# How to insert rows in MySQL DB table using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql

can anyone let me know what is the problem with this query?

```
     db.query(
            'INSERT INTO permission (programId,create,read,update,delete) VALUES(' +
                db.escape(ProgramId) +
                ',' +
                db.escape(CreateSwitchedData) +
                ',' +
                db.escape(ReadSwitchedData) +
                ',' +
                db.escape(UpdateSwitchedData) +
                ',' +
                db.escape(DeleteSwitchedData) +
                ') ',
            (err, row) => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.json('Permission Added Successfully!');
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        );
```

I'm getting this error:

```
      code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',

  errno: 1064,

  sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that ' +
    'corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to ' +
    "use near 'create,read,update,delete) VALUES(2,1,1,1,1)' at line " +
    '1',

  sqlState: '42000',

  index: 0,

  sql: 'INSERT INTO permission ' +
    '(programId,create,read,update,delete) ' +
    'VALUES(2,1,1,1,1) '
```

ProgramId is referring from another table but there key is right.
Any Help Please.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's dialect of the SQL language has a mess of reserved words. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html  `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` are among them.

Try this

```
INSERT INTO permission (programId,`create`,`read`,`update`,`delete`) VALUES('
```

Better yet, rename the columns in your table so they aren't reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using keywords inside a query without quoting them as real.

```
INSERT INTO permission (programId,`create`,`read`,`update`,`delete`)
```

This might be what you're looking for, use backticks to specify column names.